# Bluetooth scanner crashes android

Tags: android, android-studio, bluetooth, logcat

I have a problem,when i click on the button on the previuos activity to enter in this activity

```
public class Bluetooth extends AppCompatActivity{
private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> mDeviceList = new ArrayList<String>();
private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Button b1 =(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    ImageButton ib1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    super.onDestroy();
}

private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            BluetoothDevice device = intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            mDeviceList.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
            listView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mDeviceList));
        }
    }
};
```

}

the app return to the previous activity,why?
i have already defined all the activity in the android manifest.

logcat is

```
    02-28 19:01:08.672 8872-8872/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
02-28 19:01:08.694 8872-8878/? I/art: Debugger is no longer active
02-28 19:01:08.714 8872-8872/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dl.domo-1/lib/arm64
02-28 19:01:08.725 8872-8872/? I/InstantRun: Instant Run Runtime started. Android package is com.dl.domo, real application class is null.
02-28 19:01:08.802 8872-8872/? W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.dl.domo-1/lib/arm64
02-28 19:01:08.894 8872-8872/? I/HwCust: Constructor found for class android.app.HwCustHwWallpaperManagerImpl
02-28 19:01:08.937 8872-8872/? W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
02-28 19:01:09.048 8872-8872/? I/BitmapFactory: set decoder allocator to gralloc
02-28 19:01:09.048 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Alloc req: dev=0x7f9f9cc140, w=1280, h=871, format=0x1, usage=0x2000003
02-28 19:01:09.051 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Alloc handle(0x7f9966f100): interfmt=0x1, stride=1280, size=4464640
02-28 19:01:09.060 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Alloc req: dev=0x7f9f9cc140, w=3840, h=2613, format=0x1, usage=0x2000003
02-28 19:01:09.072 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Alloc handle(0x7f9966f200): interfmt=0x1, stride=3840, size=40181760
02-28 19:01:09.136 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Free handle(0x7f9966f200)
02-28 19:01:09.136 8872-8872/? I/gralloc: Free handle(0x7f9966f100)
02-28 19:01:09.150 8872-8872/? I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
02-28 19:01:09.191 8872-8897/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
```

Comment: Check the logcat. There's not enough information here.

Comment: Don't you have more logs ?
And the code of the previous activity.

Comment: I have not found the problem, but I solved by rewriting the entire class,
Thank you for answering